# setting radiobuttonlist value within a gridview using code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to set the selected value of a radiobuttonlist that is a template column within a gridview. I am having to do this using the code behind as the database field containing the data (Status) contains null values hence I cant used SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>' on the asp side.

It has been suggested that I use onRowDataBound to do this and use DataItem to retrieve the value from the datasource and used it to set the radiobuttonlist selected value but I'm not sure how to do this in vb code.

I've tried the following:

```
Protected Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim radioList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("rblActions"), RadioButtonList)

        ' this will be the object that you are binding to the grid
        Dim myObject = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        Dim sStatus As String = Convert.ToString(myObject("Status"))

        If sStatus <> Nothing Then

            radioList.SelectedValue = sStatus
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

but it hasnt work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where is the value from

Comment: the value comes from the datasource that the gridview is bound to. I have not included the Status field as part of the gridview but the sql query does return the field so it will be within the datarow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution as follows:

```
Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("rblActions"), RadioButtonList)

        Dim selected As String = e.Row.DataItem("Status").ToString

        If Not IsNothing(selected) Then
            rbl.SelectedValue = selected
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```